# Copying picture (.tga) from text content

Tags: c++, tga

I working on the creation of a game. I want to hide all my .tga files.
I concatenate the string content of all my files on a single file in order to make it illisible for players.
I want my program to load a picture by creating a temporaly .tga file from 
the saved content.

So that, I'm trying to copy a .tga file from the content of an original one.
More precisely, I read a .tga file as a text and a write it.
Eventhough Notepad++ finds original file and new file as identical, the new file can not be open as .tga file. Windows detects the size of files with 1 byte offset.

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong ?
Or may be suggest me a better way to hide my files.

Regards

Comment: How is that question related to c++, there is no c++ code involved in your question.

Comment: tga is not a text based file format but a binary format. Using a editor the is designed to work with text to copy binary data will most certainly lead to data corruption. So use the proper tools to concatenate multiple binary files.

Comment: It's very hard to advise about errors in a program we can't see... if you want a binary image file (e.g. `tga`) to be visible in a **text** editor, consider base64 encoding it.

Comment: First and foremost, what @t.niese said. Using binary data as a string is a big no-no. Second of all, even if you concatenate the binary data, the data would be rather trivially recoverable by anyone with access to it and knowledge of the TGA format specification.(e.g. http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/ ). I suggest you research existing methods for packing game data used by the many open source engines available.

Answer (score 0):

> More precisely, I read a .tga file as a **text** and a write it

Herein may lie your problem: You have to read and write the .tga file as a binary file. Otherwise, any occurence of the byte sequence 0x0D 0x0A (CR LF, Windows line ending) may be replaced with a single 0x0A (LF, Unix line ending) or vice versa, or 0x1A (DOS end of file) may be stripped or appended. Depending on the code you are using, you may also end up stripping any 0x00 (NUL) bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try to read and write as binary content on my code and i come back.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read / write with my program (c++) a .tga file as binary file but the generated file was still corrupted. The code is below.

```
std::string name = "my_picture.tga";
std::ifstream FileIn(name, std::ios_base::binary);
std::vector<char> listChar;
bool stopp = false;
if (FileIn) {
    while (!(stopp))
    {
        char xin;
        FileIn.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&xin), sizeof(char));
        listChar.push_back(xin);
        if (FileIn.eof()) stopp = true;
    }
    FileIn.close();
}

std::ofstream FileOut(".\\test.tga", std::ios_base::binary);
bool isCarierReturn = false;
for (char xout : listChar) {
    isCarierReturn = xout == '\r';
    if (!isCarierReturn) FileOut.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&xout), sizeof(char));
}
FileOut.close();
```

I compared the original file and the new one on a hexadecimal reader and files are effectively different.

The difference between original and new file consists in a mismatch on lines ending, instead of just having 0x0A ('\n') on the original file, the new file had the byte sequence 0x0D 0x0A ('\r' and '\n'). On some other pictures the generated file was incomplete, the break is always before a 0x1A value (as said @Christoph Lipka).

I manage to write the right sequence by testing if the char is a carrier return, the char is not written on this case and only the byte 0x0D is skipped, see below :

```
std::ofstream FileOut(".\\test.tga", std::ios_base::binary);
bool isCarrierReturn = false;
char xout_p1 = '\0';
if (listChar.size() >= 1) xout_p1 = listChar.at(0);
for (unsigned i(0); i < listChar.size(); i++) {
    char xout = xout_p1;
    if (i < listChar.size() - 1) xout_p1 = listChar.at(i + 1);
    else xout_p1 = '\0';
    isCarrierReturn = xout == '\r' && xout_p1 == '\n';
    if (!isCarrierReturn) FileOut.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&xout), sizeof(char));
}
FileOut.close();
```

The incomplete file reading is solved by reading the file as binary file.

It works.